# Media query breakpoints fail on some tablets

Tags: css, media-queries, breakpoints

I have a media query breakpoint at 768, and it works for the Apple iPad in portrait mode (768 pixel width), but some settings, like padding-top and certain font sizes, fail on a Google Nexus 7 at 800 pixels wide.  I tried a new breakpoint at 800 but nothing changed.

Also, I tested on Apple iPad Pro 12.9 at http://responsivechecker.net/device/ipad-pro-12-9.  In landscape at 1366x1024 the site has a few issues, and in portrait at 1024x1366 it also has a few issues (but not many).

My breakpoints are 320, 576, 768, and 992 and 1200.  Based on what I’ve seen I think I may need to add a breakpoint at 1440 and revise the 1200 breakpoint.  My desktop monitor is 1454, so I would use 1440 to target desktops and wider.

I have two questions:

1. Why would a 768px breakpoint fail on a device at 800px?
2. I know it’s not a science, but what are the best breakpoints?

All of my problems are with the higher resolution tablets, but I’m just not clear on what breakpoints to use.

Thanks for any insights.

Comment: have you reviewed this question? [How to target Galaxy Nexus and Nexus 7 with media queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12557353/how-to-target-galaxy-nexus-and-nexus-7-with-media-queries)

Comment: Thanks for the link to that article.  I hadn't seen it.